# QFileDialog.getOpenFileName Loop problem in a QGis plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

I wrote a QGIS plugin and in the pyQt5 Dialog , I use a button connected to a QFileDialog.getOpenFileName function to select a dxf file.
I aim to open the dxf file for controls.

In the def run() method here's the connexion:

```
self.dlg.pbDxf.clicked.connect(self.setDxf)
```

The function connected:

```
def setDxf(self):
    ''' Choose the DXF file'''
    file = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "DXF Import", "", "DXF File (*.dxf)")
```

My problem is that when I call the plugin, the file path is still written in the edit box and when I chose a file and clic OK, there's a loop and I have the select dialog again.
Any idea of how I could prevent that?

Comment: When asking for help to debug code, please provide the entirety of the code or a reproducible example. Otherwise, if it is not a straightforward error it will be impossible to answer.

Comment: getOpenFileName() should return a tuple. Try: file, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, "DXF Import", "", "DXF File (*.dxf)")